# How to view hourly results during the time specified in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a query that returns a list of timezones as a result when the following conditions are specified.

```sql
select day, hour
...
where
  target_datetime between '2021-08-01 00:00:00' and '2021-08-01 23:59:59'
```

```json
[
  { 'day': '2021-08-01', 'hour': 0 },
  { 'day': '2021-08-01', 'hour': 1 },
  { 'day': '2021-08-01', 'hour': 2 },
...
  { 'day': '2021-08-01', 'hour': 23 }
]
```

How can I get this?

Comment: You can use the [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html) function with a step of 1 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `generate_series` to create the records from the time interval, and `jsonb_build_objebt` with `jsonb_agg` to create your json document:

```
SELECT 
  jsonb_agg(
    jsonb_build_object(
      'day',tm::date,
      'hour',EXTRACT(HOUR FROM tm)))
FROM generate_series('2021-08-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, 
                     '2021-08-01 23:59:59'::timestamp,
                      interval '1 hour') j (tm);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=957b6a36848639d6ab9b56d7f3d3088d)

Comment: I was looking for exactly this. thanks so much!